# How can I change textbox properties in a line?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I want to change the fontweight property in a line.

```
TextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
TextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
TextBox.Text += "Send\t:\t";

TextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
TextBox.Text += (MsgTextBox.Text+"\n");
```

However previous fontweight changing doesn't work.

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyZVu.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Actually I want to know when does the TextBox updated.

Thank you.

Comment: A textbox doesn't allow this, you must use a RichTextBox

Comment: You will want to use a TextBlock alternatively. You can add Runs to Textblocks and apply specific formatting to each Run. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it with textblock

```
                public TextBlockCodeBehindSample()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                    tb.Inlines.Add("An example on ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("the TextBlock control ") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
                    tb.Inlines.Add("using ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("inline ") { FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic });
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("text formatting ") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
                    tb.Inlines.Add("from ");
                    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Code-Behind") { TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline });
                    tb.Inlines.Add(".");
                    this.Content = tb;
            }
```

[Looks like](https://ibb.co/mEUNd5)